# Create nonclustered index on uniqueidentifier type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, index-tuning

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[session]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [session_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [supervisor_id] [int] NULL,
    some columns ..

    CONSTRAINT [PK_session] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl2]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [close_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [edit_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [session_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    some columns ..

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl2] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have those two tables which I can join on the `session_id` column. There are more than 20 000 rows in each table, and the join is too slow. Is it a good idea to create a nonclustered index on `session_id` columns which are of `uniqueidentifier` type? Or there is another way to do the join faster ?

Edit:

For example query is like :

```
SELECT some_columns...
FROM [dbo].[session] s
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl2] t2 on s.[session_id] = t2.[session_id]
WHERE t2.some_column = something
```

Comment: Can you add a sample query ?

Comment: @itzikPaz I edit question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your sample query, you must have two separate `NonClustered` Indexes on `Session_id` column for both tables. Further it must contain columns that are being used by `SELECT` clause to avoid [bookmark lookups](http://www.connectsql.com/2011/01/sql-server-bookmark-lookups-query.html).

**Fill factor for indexes on uniqueidentifier:** If only key column (like in your case) is uniqueidentifier then you can fill all the page (Fill Factor = 100), as there are no chances of value updates for this column.

But **drawback** for index creation on `uniqueidentifier` column is that `GUID` is a wide column (16 bytes to be specific) and contains a unique combination of 33 uppercase and numeric characters and are randomly generated by SQL Server hence huge chances of page split and index fragmentation. Using `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`  (SQL SERVER 2008 and above) to insert values instead of `NEWID()` can resolve this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't term a uniqueidentifier "wide". It is a 128-bit integer, not a char() or binary(). It is just two bigints stuck together. :-)